# Subversive: new branch naming and folder tree

Tags: eclipse, svn, branch, subversive

I have an issue with Subversive.

I'm trying to create a new branch starting from the trunk tree.

The project has the following structure:

```
- project
      |---- trunk
              | ---- src

      |---- branches
               |---- branch1
                        |----- src
```

I want to create a branch "branch2", in way to have the following structure:

```
- project
      |---- trunk
              | ---- src

      |---- branches
               |---- branch1
                        |----- src
               |---- branch2
                        |----- src
```

But subversive create instead the following structure:

```
- project
      |---- trunk
              | ---- src

      |---- branches
               |---- branch1
                        |----- src
               |---- branch2
                        |----- trunk
                                 |---- src
```

There is an **unwanted trunk folder** under the branche name: how can I do to avoid this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the command line you used to do it and people can point out what needs to be fixed.

Comment: I'm not using the command line, I'm using the Eclipse GUI plugin (subversive)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an incompatibility issue between subversive 4.0.3 and Eclipse Neon.

Installed on STS, the plugin subversive 4.0.3 performs the branches creation in the right way.